# remove backgroud gradient in jquery ui

Tags: html, jquery-ui

How can I remove this gradient from this auto suggestion list in jquery UI ? I have used jquery UI for this search bar  that shows list of 10 options. I cannot remove this gradient.

[image]the stye sheet is :

```
.ui-autocomplete {
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color:none;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

* html .ui-autocomplete {
    height: 100px;


<script>
        var optionarray = [];
          var a  =  ["option1? , option 2, option 3, option 4" ];
         $(function() {
}
```

How can I remove this gradient from this auto suggestion list in HTML? I have used jquery UI for this search bar and cannot remove this gradient when showing lists/ options in search bar.

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5bT6.png)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: why no one is answering my question?

Comment: What gradient? ... is there a specific property? Inspect the element with the browser's tool to see what the property might be.

Comment: i added the pic of inspect element. The gradient / background gray color in first image. is like i have to overwrite teh jquery UI css?

Comment: To the right side of the inspect window, what are the CSS properties for that element? Somewhere, there is property with the gray color, or its hex value equivalent. I'm thinking that the top-level `<div>` (`<ul>`, or whatever the parent element to all the `<li>` elements may be) has this value.

Comment: i think it is <ul> and then <li> contains all  all option.  i have added two images  now which property to edit ?

Comment: i tried to change few background properties but it does not seem to be working

Comment: Curious that the `.ui-widget-content` has a (repeated) background image. Can you uncheck that CSS property in the inspector to see if it goes away?

Comment: No it does not go away.

Comment: To ensure that we're talking about the same thing, there appears to be 5 color bands in the first image... white, a light gray, then a light orange (or red?), then a darker gray, then a taller (appears to be) another light blue/gray last. Which one specifically? ... or is this online somewhere to check? If not, maybe add more HTML/CSS example into the question to replicate.

Comment: i am talking about 3rd color rite under the yellow color. that i something i do not want. i ahve updated image  with a circle to show what i want to get rid of

Comment: Ok, so in the inspector, instead of unchecking, does anything change if you delete the background property there? Do not reload the page, as it will only come back. It should be dynamic when deleted or unchecked. Also, if possible, can you capture the screenshot when the element hovered in the inspector has the upper page area highlighted by the inspector as well? That will ensure the correct area is targeted.

Comment: perfect.  i was reloading that is y it was  loading old value. now if i want to change it permanently what should i do?

Comment: There are a couple of ways... you can redefine the same class without the background. (would have to be done at a point after the other CSS, meaning yours must be last to override), or maybe try to do `$('.ui-widget-content').css('background', 'none');` or perhaps `'transparent'` instead of `'none'`, whichever may be better for your needs.